# How to substring with double slashes?

Tags: java, apache-commons

Why does the following not print `www.google.de`?

```
String url = "http://www.google.de";
System.out.println(org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.substringAfter("://", url)); 
//prints "" empty
```

Comment: What is `StringUtils`?

Comment: @Axel it's a static `String` utility provided by the Apache Commons framework. Well, most likely that :)

Comment: `org.apache.commons.lang`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have inverted the arguments in the signature.

You need to parametrize with the input `String` first, **then** the separator.

See API [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#substringAfter%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use split function like:

```
String url = "http://www.google.de";
System.out.println(url.split("//")[1]);
```

[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/frP6Rd)